# MeshLab 2020.07 hangs on startup

Tags: meshlab

I am trying to run MeshLab 2020.07 on Windows 10 Home 1909 64-bit. It seems to have installed successfully. When I launch it, the UI opens with an empty project and then becomes unresponsive. In task manager it uses about 12% of my CPU. I let it do this for a while (30 minutes) to see if it ever does something else, but it doesn't. I have 16GB of RAM, an NVIDIA GeForce GTC 1660 Ti, and an onboard Intel UHD Graphics 630 with my i7-9750. Any ideas on how I can get it running?

Answer (score 0):

I went into Nvidia Control Panel and made my Nvidia GPU the Primary by default. This resolved the problem, and similar problem I was having with Meshmixer.